# Android ListView not displaying incomming messages after returning to the activity

Tags: android, listview, message, openfire, smack

I am trying to create an chat client even though i have an issue. When I open the app for first time and I open a chat (ListView) it works perfectly.

[image]

```
04-17 07:19:51.681  10020-10081/com.example.example E/SENDER ANSWER:﹕ yes
04-17 07:19:55.494  10020-10081/com.example.example E/SENDER ANSWER:﹕ hi
```

but when I leave the chat with the back buttom and i wanna get back to the window It doesnt display received messages but displays mines

[image]

after I sent "second" the other user sent :

```
04-17 07:21:17.246  10020-10081/com.example.example E/SENDER ANSWER:﹕ second time and doesnt work
```

and it didn't displayed on the listview.
here is my Code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    chatmanager.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
                @Override
                public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
                if (!createdLocally) {
                    chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                            Log.e("SENDER ANSWER:", message.getBody());

                            sender_messages = message.getBody();

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    populateConversation(sender_messages, true);

                                    populateConversationView();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    });
                }

                }
            });
}
```

maybe it doesn't have to be with the chat listener because it is receiving the messages but just not displaying. I would appreciate any help

```
public void populateConversationView(){
 final ArrayAdapter<Message_Provider> adapter = new MyListAdapter();


messagesList.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            messagesList.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
        }
    });

 private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message_Provider> { // Done
        public MyListAdapter(){
            super(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.chat_conversation, messages);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.source_message, parent, false);
            }


            Message_Provider currentContact = messages.get(position);

            TextView myMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.senderMessege);

            myMessage.setText(currentContact.getMessage());

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams parameter = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (currentContact.getSender()){
                parameter.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                myMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_messages);

            }else {
                parameter.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                myMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_message);

            }
            myMessage.setLayoutParams(parameter);


            return itemView;
        }
```

I was testing the whole day and it is like when i go back and i open a new activity the chat listener increments the previews one and not the new one and i think it is because of the runOnUiThread.

Comment: let me know the code of your  adapater.

Comment: post your adapter code. People can help u better then

Comment: I just checked and when i return to the chat the message received is not entering to the populateListView Funtion and i think is because of the  runOnUiThread and when i comeback it is running on the previous UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED THIS, OMG! after hours of debugging XD I needed to close the chat in the listener

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        populateConversation(sender_messages, true);
        populateConversationView();
        chat.close(); // HERE

        }  
    });
```

I post this because there are beginners like me and may get this problem too.